# NSPropertyListSerialization after parsing an XML

Tags: iphone, ios, xml-serialization, xml-rpc

I need to know if I am in the right track here. I am parsing an XML-RPC in iPhone (using the eczarny framework) and I am getting an array with objects. I create an NSData and store an object. After that I am trying to deserialize it but get en error.
Code:

```
NSArray *result = [response object];
    NSData *data = [result objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Data %@",data);
    NSDictionary * message = nil;
    NSString * error = nil;
    message = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:data mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainers format:nil errorDescription:&error];
```

The nslog:

```
Data {

     DESCRIPTION = "Standardverkn";
        FLAGS = 0;
        NAME = "Fenster OG3";
        RECEIVER = "IEQ007:3";
        SENDER = "IEQ0043:1"; 
}
```

The error:

```
 -[__NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e4bd50
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `[result objectAtIndex:0]` is not an NSData, it is an NSDictionary.

Comment: thanks!!!! I thought all this time it was nsdata. how can I reward you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[result objectAtIndex:0]` is already an NSDictionary. You don't need to deserialize it. You can just directly use it as the `message`.

(If it is an NSData, the NSLog will show something like `<12345678 9abcdef0 ...>`.)